# preg - Difference between Search Patterns with [] and without

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

It seems I am not able to understand something very basic with preg regex Patterns in PHP.

What is the difference between these Regex Patterns:

- `\b([A-Z...]...)`
- `[\b]{1}([A-Z...]...)`

The Pattern should start with a word boundary, but why is the result different, when I put it in `[]{1}` ??
The first one works like I expected, but the second not. The problem is, that I want to put more into the `[]`, so that the pattern can start with a word boundary OR a small character `[a-z]`.

Thank you!

Example Text:

```
Race1529/05/201512:45K4 Senior Men 1000m
LaneName(s)NFBib(s)TimeRank250m500m750m
152
Martin SCHUBERT / Lukas REUSCHENBACH155
11
153
151Kostja STROINSKI / Kai SPENNER
03:07.740
GER
8
```

I want to find the names of the racers. Sometimes they have a word-break (`\b`) at the beginning, sometimes not. (But i need the word-break.)

```
$pattern = '#\b(['.$GB.$KB.'\s\-]{2,40})\s(['.$GB.'\'\-\s]{2,40})[0-9]{0,5}#';
```

(`$GB` is a variable with all Uppercase Letters, `$KB` with lower case letters)

`preg_match_all` gives me all racers where the Name has a word-break at the beginning. (In this example Schubert, Reuschenbach, Spenner) but of course not Stroinski. So, I try this:

```
$pattern = '#[\b0-9]+(['.$GB.$KB.'\s\-]{2,40})\s(['.$GB.'\'\-\s]{2,40})[0-9]{0,5}#';
```

Does not work. Even if i remove the 0-9 and only put [\b]{1} at the beginning it doesn't find any hit.

I don't see the difference between `\b` and `[\b]{1}`. It seems to be a very basic misunderstanding.

Comment: Is the second example even valid? I think it's a lot easier if you give us sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[\b]` is a [character class](http://php.net/manual/pl/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) that only matches a [*backspace* char](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm) (`\u0008`).

See [PHP regex reference](http://php.net/manual/pl/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> note that `"\b"` has a different meaning, namely the backspace character, inside a character class

Also, `.{1}` = `.`, the `{1}` [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) is always redundant and only makes sense when your patterns are built dynamically from variables.

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution: \b has different meanings if used inside a character class or not. Did not realize that. Thank you!

PHP.net:
All the sequences that define a single byte value can be used both inside and outside character classes. In addition, inside a character class, the sequence "\b" is interpreted as the backspace character (hex 08). Outside a character class it has a different meaning (see below).